# Styles and dropdowns are gone

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, ods

Using PHPSpreadsheet, when populating an existing spreadsheet, all styles, conditional formatting, dropdowns, etc. are gone.

How can I retain the original settings while writing to php://output?

Here's a screenshot of what the base ODS file should look like:
[image: Standard look of the RASCI tool for ISO/IEC27001:2013]

When opening this template and writing values from the database to the R/A/S/C/I cells, the outcome is this:

[image: Outputted spreadsheet]

Here is the code I have so far. You can ignore $modulePath etc. as that is just the lookup of the full system path to the file.

```
$original = $modulePath . '/resources/ISO27k-RASCI-tool.ods';

    $reader = IOFactory::createReader('Ods');
    $sheet = $reader->load($original);

    $sheet->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
    $sheet->setHasMacros(true);

    $col = range('A', 'Z');
    $teams = $this->dataRecord->Annex()->Teams();
    foreach ($teams as $i => $team) {
        $sheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col[$i + 2] . '1', $team->Name);
    }

    $writer = new Ods($sheet);
    $writer->save('php://output');
```

Comment: can you be a little more specific? if you could add some code that would be helpfull

Comment: Yes, done. I realise my question was a bit unclear indeed. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: have you tried explicitly setting the `$reader->setReadDataOnly(false);` option?

Comment: Just did, no difference, sadly

Comment: can you try to use `$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Ods');` instead of `new Ods()`,
I also noticed you arent't setting the response header for the file_type `header('Content-Type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet');`

Comment: Hi @YouriKoeman, the response headers are actually set, however, I didn't think it was relevant for the problem, so I left them out.

Using the createWriter() method doesn't solve the problem though. Still all styling etc. are lost.

Comment: ok i will try to locally replicate your enviroment more closely, what:
-php version
-phpspreadsheet version

and if you could supply a modifed file (with all data that you do not want tot share removed)

Comment: php -v

PHP 7.3.11-1+0~20191026.48+debian8~1.gbpf71ca0 (cli)

phpoffice/phpspreadsheet                                 1.9.0

More about the project can be found here: https://github.com/Firesphere/isocompliance

The base ODS spreadsheet can be found in the "resources" folder. I hope that from the poorly documented code, you see what I'm trying to achieve.

Simplest would be to attempt to write some team names to C1, C2, C3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of that not all excel/ods [styling commands](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#styles) are implemented in phpspreedsheet.
As well there is no "pivottable" and "format as table" support.

Your table looks like you use at least "format as table".

The problem is that you crate a new file and your file is only a kind of template. Unsupported cell styling will be skipped. The only solution is that you must style your output with the [styling commands](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#styles).